# What's the best practice for sharepoint security update?

Tags: sharepoint-server, security, cumulative-update, hotfix

I am confused about updating a SharePoint farm with security fixes

- Is it recommended to update it via Microsoft Update?
- Is it recommended to update it from CU Full Server Package?
- Are there other methods?
- Generally, what's the best practice?

I will appreciate a detailed answer with trusted reference for each scenario

Answer (score 3):

I communicated with Stefan Gobber who is escalation engineer at Microsoft about SharePoint security fixes through MU/WU he said

- SharePoint fixes for server products will continue to be available via Microsoft Update.
- Install CU if it will fix issue on farm,
- Never install CU on production till apply it on test.

I tried to summarize our conversation and asked him

Security update through windows update and CU through download center, right?

> His answer was "Correct"

I also asked him is there any affect on farm during installing security patch from Microsoft updates, he said

> SharePoint 2010 and 2013 allow to continue execution without PSCONFIG after installing fixes.so you can schedule running configuration wizard after securing patch installation is finished.

For more details read

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/02/26/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update/

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint updates should not be installed via MU/WU as they require manual intervention post-installation through the Config Wizard.

As for CU vs. Security, totally up to you and your testing. CUs include all updates between the previous Service Pack (and/or RTM) and the current month, including the security update.

CUs generally require more testing on your part, though.

Comment: Thank you fo your answer , should you provide me with a reference for that ? I also checked http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=523 and this http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=556 that confused me more  :)

Comment: To which part are you looking for a reference?

Comment: for this point please "SharePoint updates should not be installed via MU/WU as they require manual intervention post-installation through the Config Wizard."

Comment: Dear @Trevor Seward Are you here ?!

Comment: Lots of details here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338.aspx.  As all SharePoint updates require the Config Wizard/psconfig to be run manually after each server has the patch installed, it isn't recommended to use MU/WU to automatically install SharePoint patches.

Comment: Should you tell me  Why it is not recommended ? is it because it requires running Config wizard after the update ? is it will effect on the farm if the fixes have been pushed to SharePoint servers but the config wizard is not run ?

Comment: This is a great link but I think it talks about the full server package cumulative update , but I talk especially about security update fro SharePoint from the microsoft update ? where security update to require to patched periodically to close VAs, not like CU that should be applied on demand and to fix software bugs or add new enhancement , please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Please read my previous responses as to why it is not recommended. All SharePoint updates are treated the same.

Comment: I am sorry , I am really confused and this is the last quest Is SharePoint 2010 and 2013 allow continuing execution without PSCONFIG after installing security fixes ? if yes so I can schedule running the Config wizard after each Microsoft update without installing non-security (Functional) fixes that may be not needed to install I only need security fixes ? I apologize for disturbing

Comment: You must install the same patch on all servers regardless of what type of patch it is. You must run the config wizard/psconfig on all SharePoint servers in the farm after the patch has been applied to all servers. You should not have extended time between installing and running the Config Wizard/psconfig. Since installation requires downtime, it is best to do both at the same time.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply , and this is my case , Shany A K
March 16, 2015 at 9:43 am
Hi Stefan 
In my company ( probably most of the companies ) the windows update done by a separate team who push the patches through SCCM etc . This will be happening different time according to the maintenance window . SharePoint patching required a PSCONFIG execution
after the binary installation , which is not required in other OS patches . So PSCONFIG is now difficult if SharePoint patches are through Windows Update. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: and this sefen reply Reply
Stefan Goßner
March 16, 2015 at 2:52 pm
Hi Shany,
SharePoint 2010 and 2013 allow to continue execution without PSCONFIG after installing fixes. So you can schedule a maintenance window where you can run PSCONFIG.

Comment: Ref : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/02/26/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update/

Comment: You're free to follow whichever advise you'd like to.

Comment: I understand your point and thank you for your help and let me check other suggestions before set as answer

Answer (score 2):

Trevor already give you details on this. I tell what we do.

We prefer CU on security patches but if there is service pack then that is our priority. We never install every cu unless it fix one of the issue related to our farm. As CUs are cumulative and contains previous cu fixes, So we apply CU in our farm every 3rd quarter.

Reason, this required down time, also require testing and sign off from customer after testing. Which take couple of months. So we schedule everything in advance and perform hard testing.

I would not recommend to install security patches via Windows update, due to config wizard requirement. Also during the installation of patch farm goes down and can cause corruption of data if user are working.

It should be a controlled manner,

- pick the cu which u want install
- test in lower farm and ask customer do testing
- sign off from customer
- schedule production
- take the farm backup before applying CU in case DR you can recover it.

Rest you decide upon your own requirements and limitations

Comment: Dear @Waqas Sarwar MCSE thank you for this useful information , regarding this point "during the installation of patch farm goes down and can cause corruption of data if the user is working". are you mean windows patch installation can effect on the farm ?